# Localhost - Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cookies

I just set up this multisite WordPress on my localhost. It consists of a domain (`local.example.com`) and 2 subdomains (`local.site2.example.com` and `local.site3.example.com`).

Everything works perfectly for the root domain, I can log in and go to the backend just fine, but when I try to log into any of the subdomains I get the "Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser." error.

- Yes, my cookies are enabled.
- I tried the wp-config define hack
- Cleared cache
- Disabled plugins and themes
- Updated to 4.0

I realize this has been posted many times before, but I haven't seen a recent post for this nor I have seen the multisite in localhost version of that error.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress administration can be asked on [wordpress.se]. In the future, please ask such questions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said "I tried the wp-config" define hack. I'm not sure what you mean by that but in my case it worked by setting the one below in the `wp-config.php` file:

`define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);`

On the other hand, if you are using Apache as a web server then check in your Apache configuration if you have [`enabled mod_security`](http://opensourceforu.efytimes.com/2011/08/securing-apache-part-10-mod_security) turned ON. This will prevent, among others, the cookie thing. So if it is enabled then just try to disable this module and check again. If it is the cause of the problem then check its configuration, particularly any settings related to cookies.

The settings for this Apache module may be stored within a file named `modsecurity.conf`. They may be found even in Apache's `httpd.conf` as well. You got the idea, anyway.

Comment: It helped.. Thank you

Comment: this helped for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried just add `define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', false )`, but it didn't work for me.

this is what makes my multisite work locally:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', ''); 
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', false );
```