# How can I eliminate the WordPress error "Error: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress."

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I keep getting this error...

[image]

I tried adding this to `functions.php` but it didn't change anything

```
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH ) {
    setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
}
```

Nothing is working.
I've tried on multiple browsers and devices to make sure it's not specific to one particular browser or device, but it happens everywhere.

**INTERESTING TO NOTE:**

- It appears only once, then I can log in with the same credentials.
- If I am logged in and log out and redirected to `?loggedout=true&wp_lang=en_US` I can also log in without the error.
- I tested some more and adding anything to the end of `wp-login.php` will allow a login, so it's only the original `wp-login.php` that has problems but not anything with an addendum.

What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Localhost - Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25741485/localhost-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these help you : [Link](https://ultimateblocks.com/how-to-fix-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-error-in-wordpress/#:%7E:text=Cookies%20can%20be%20blocked%20by,not%20supported%20by%20your%20browser.) or [Link](https://wp-staging.com/how-to-fix-the-error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser/)